# Unable to use namespace from project after including reference? F# C#

Tags: c#, f#

I'm following a guide from Tomas Petricek on pluralsight. I'm trying to make a C# unit test project to test some methods from an F# library, however even after adding the reference to the F# project in the C# project I can't use any of the methods as they are not recognized and when trying to use the namespace from the F# project it is an unknown namespace.

Most solutions to questions like these appear to be the targeting of different frameworks, however, I am targeting 4.5.2 in both projects.

What could be going wrong?

Comment: One thing to check is to make sure that the F# project compiles without errors - if you cannot compile it, the C# project will not see anything. If that's not the case, can you share your project in some way? It's hard to see what might be causing this without more information....

Comment: Haha you were right I hadn't built the F# project yet. Silly mistake. I'm still honing my skills! Thanks Tomas you're my hero lol!

Comment: I'm glad this helped! I turned it into a proper answer with some more details on how this works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing to check is to make sure that the F# project is compiled and there were no errors.

When a C# project references an F# library, the C# compiler will look at the resulting `dll` file and provide auto-complete based on the compiled library. This is different than when you reference C# library from a C# project, because in this case, the auto-completion is based on the checks that Visual Studio does in background.

This means that, whenever you change the public API of the F# library, you need to recompile it to make sure that the C# project sees the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

For me the project build without issues and despite multiple `dotnet clean; dotnet build;` the IDE was still complaining. It said that my newly added modules of the references projects were not available in the test project.

In the end restarting VsCode did the trick.

I'm using VsCode 1.63 with Iodine and both projects are F# projects.

Comment: Had same issue with VS 2022. Sheesh, I hate these types of errors.